# Docusaurus "Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for" error

Tags: reactjs, jsx, markdown, docusaurus

I have a lot of old documentation *.md files in WikiJS format. I need to convert them to docusaurus-compatible md format.

There are some strings like `"http://<gateway-ip>:8889/ad-groups/"` that are not wrapped in code blocks. (Edit: i even needed to wrap it here, because StackOverflow deleted `<gateway-ip>` part from it).

When i'm building docusaurus i have an error

```
SyntaxError: ... Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <gateway-ip>.
```

I am able to reproduce this error in [Docusaurus playground](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/distracted-burnell-0yfve5?file=%2Fdocs%2Fintro.md&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A36%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A9%2C%22startColumn%22%3A36%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A9%7D%5D) just by adding the problematic string to it. So i assume that Docusaurus thinks that  is jsx tag. But i'm not using *.mdx file, it's just *.md.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?